# What's the correct plural of Jedi and Sith?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, sith

Lots of times, I see people using "Jedis" and "Siths" (I also use that), but it doesn't feel right. Or, maybe, it's correct.

Is there official word on this? What's the correct plural of Jedi and Sith?

Comment: The words "Jedis" and "Siths" aren't used in any of the scripts or novelisations.

Comment: It's actually a good question. I see the incorrect plural forms often all over the Internet. This will be a useful question to point people to. You got my +1.

Comment: Just think of the Jedi and the Sith as fish.

Comment: Maybe just like latin words Jedi is plural, and the singular form is Jedus? :p

Comment: @Lyrion Haha.. That's awesome!

Comment: @Daft: there’s no such thing as a fish. But what about fishes?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**Jedi**:

> Mace Windu: ...you must realize there aren't enough Jedi to protect the Republic. We are keepers of the peace, not soldiers. -- Episode II

**Sith**:

It's difficult to find conclusive proof that the plural of "Sith" is "Sith" because (a) there are so few Sith and (b) the plural is usually given as "Sith Lords". These are the best I can find in the scripts:

> Yoda: Destroy the Sith, we must. -- Episode III

and

> Anakin: The Sith rely on their passion for their strength. They think inward, only about themselves. -- Episode III

Yoda and Anakin may be referring to the Sith Order rather than multiple Sith (Sidious and Vader in Yoda's case). In Anakin's case in particular, though, he uses the plural "their", "they", and "themselves" in the two sentences, so it's quite possible he is referring to individual members of the Sith Order. It would also make little sense to say that the Sith Order has "passion for their strength", so it's more likely he's referring to individual Sith members.

Also, this [archived page from starwars.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20140213004918/http://starwars.com/explore/encyclopedia/groups/sith/) describes the Sith and says:

> Power-hungry Sith practitioners fought amongst themselves and dwindled their numbers. Weakened by infighting, the Sith were easily wiped out by the Jedi.

Again, this may refer to the Sith Order rather than multiple Sith, but the previous sentence refers to Sith practitioners rather than the order.

As @Richard noted in a comment, there is no use of "Jedis" or "Siths" in any of the scripts (even in the non-dialogue scene descriptions).

Comment: +1. Like your quote shows, sometimes Jedi or Sith are used as quasi-adjectives, and the noun they're applied to will get pluralized. Sith practitioner**s**. Jedi Master**s**, but never the Jedi/Sith themselves.

Comment: I have my doubts that citing Yoda to answer *grammar* questions leads to somewhere…

Comment: @CreationEdge Yeah, using the words as quasi-adjectives makes it difficult to find conclusive proof that the plurals don't end in "s".

Comment: @Holger Yoda says his words out of order but doesn't use incorrect plurals. Nonetheless, I found and added a quote by Anakin that I think is more conclusive. Better now?

Comment: @Null: I know that, as far as I know, all uses are consistent and I agree with your answer. It’s just irresistible to comment on cites of Yoda in a grammar question… or well, to comment on cites of Yoda in a grammar question, irresistible it is…

Comment: @Holger Heh, yes, a good joke, it is. But also useful, it was. Spurred me to find a better quote, it did.

Comment: @Null:   I don't think there's enough focus on the quasi-adjective point.   It is entirely idiomatic and grammatical to use the+adjective in the singular to refer to an entire group ("The meek shall inherit...").   Can't find a good link (here's one https://www.englishforums.com/English/DefiniteArticlePlusAdjectiveMean-OtherPossible/qwnwg/post.htm), but if you think about it, you will realize this construction is common.   The quote from Yoda can be exactly that.

Comment: ... the point being, "Destroy the Sith, we must" doesn't tell us anything about what the plural of Sith is.   (It's "Sith" -- this quote just doesn't show it.)    It could have been "Destroy the villainous, we must." and it doesn't tell us what the plural of "villain" is.

Comment: @Holger Technically, Yoda’s speaking is grammatical, just unusual. The word order works as far as English grammar rules are concerned.

Comment: @ThePopMachine My answer says that Yoda may be referring to the Sith Order (singular). But he may be referring to the Sith members (plural). If Yoda had been more explicit, he might have said "Destroy the *two* Sith, we must", which would have to be a case of plural "Sith".

Comment: @Null:   I'm merely pointing out that you're correct to say it's difficult to find conclusive proof.   But I think you're missing my point.   Even if he's referring to the Sith (plural) this quote doesn't show the plural is "Sith" because that construction takes the ***adjective***, which looks like the ***grammatically singular noun***.

Comment: @KRyan: Yoda might be correct according to grammar rules but if you cite someone to prove a point, you need the addressee’s trust in his/her authority regarding that point. Otherwise, if you need another cite (e.g. to language grammar rules) to prove the authority, the first cite misses the point. But anyway, it’s unlikely that the language spoken a long time ago in a galaxy far away is English so maybe the translators are to blame.

Comment: @ThePopMachine The construction could be using the adjective, or it could be using the plural form of the noun (e.g. "We must destroy the Soviets.").

Comment: @Null:   The answer goes on an on about how is could be that it's using the singular "Sith" because it's short for "the Sith Order" etc.   This is a possible explanation.   But for some reason, you refuse to accept another equally good explanation for why this doesn't show the plural is "Sith".   When you give one explanation and not another, you are giving a misleading and incomplete answer, even if the conclusion is the same.    Speak personally, I don't find the explanation convincing.... cont'd

Comment: ...    What would be more idiomatic:  "The evil must be vanquished" or "The Soviet must be vanquished" when you mean the "Soviet Union".   This is the argument you are making.   I'm not saying it's known to be wrong, but it's not known to be right either, and I don't see why you're fighting a perfectly good explanation.

Answer (score 31):

The correct answer is “Jedi” and “Sith”.

> *Obi-Wan:* But he still has much to learn, Master. His abilities have made him... well arrogant.
>
> *Yoda:* Yes. Yes. A flaw more and more common among Jedi. Too sure of themselves they are. Even the older, more experienced ones.

---

> *Obi-Wan:* You were the chosen one! It was said that you would destroy the Sith, not join them. You were to bring balance to the force, not leave it in darkness.
>
> *Anakin Skywalker:* [shouts] I hate you.

Comment: Your second quote doesn't really illustrate your point; "Sith" is also a word to describe the group, so saying "the Sith" isn't using it as a plural

Comment: Why did you include Yoda who doesn't know grammar well?

Comment: @JasonBaker He is clearly referring to them in plural, see " not join them".

Comment: @SS Yoda changes sentence structure, he seems to have a firm grasp on plurality and all other grammar. I'll find you another quote if the fact there's never an "s" on "jedi" or "sith" anywhere isn't enough.

Comment: @JasonBaker, it does illustrate it. Would you say "the German" when talking about German citizenry?

Comment: @PaulDraper On reflection I think that probably is the way Obi-Wan is using the word; my confusion was because "the Sith" is a common shorthand for "the Sith Order/Empire/Triumvirate/whatever-identity-we're-using-this-week"

Comment: The most recent edit here (by @Daft) appears to remove all references to Sith or Jedi from this answer. Can we revert an edit?

Answer (score 1):

Pre-Visla:
You're not Jedi, so what are you?

Darth Maul:
We are Sith.

Pre-Visla:
Do you serve Count Dooku?

Darth Maul:
I serve no one.

Pre-Visla:
I thought there can only be two Sith: a master and an apprentice?

INDISPUTABLE EVIDENCE!

Comment: Can you clarify where this quote comes from?

Comment: As well as what another user has said it might be helpful to [edit] this to explicitly state what your actual answer to the question is here.

Comment: Could you explain how this is any more "indisputable" than the existing answers?

Answer (score -8):

"The Jedi" refers collectively to the group. You can probably go either way with the plural: "There are 3 Jedi(s) in the next room" / "There are 3 Jedi masters in the next room".

"Siths" sounds like you have a speech impediment.

And don't quote Yoda here. Bad example his grammar is, mmmmmyesssssssss.

Comment: Yoda's grammar is actually perfect, just not usual.

Comment: -1. Answer is incorrect and poorly formatted as well.